# Specific bracha tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we have seperate tags for specific kinds of *Brachos*?

e.g. We have tags for `blesssing` and `sight`.
How about `Sight-Blessings` for ברכות ראיה?

Answer (score 2):

I think we should have separate tags for separate kinds of blessings. I think, specifically, that we should separate the *birchos hanehenin* (blessings over food and the like) from the others, possibly even splitting between *b'racha rishona* and *b'racha acharona*. Whether the remaining *b'racha*-related questions are numerous enough to warrant a split, and what split, I don't know.

I agree with ["If we do sub-divide, let's make sure the new tags have enough questions to warrant it"](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1544). But I think *birchos hanehenin* has enough.

---

*Edit:* The [blessing](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blessing) tag has been used not only for things like blessings said before eating, as part of prayer, and before slaughtering a steer, but also for blessings given by one person to another, like "mazal tov!". I think we should split those off, too.

Comment: _birchos hamitzvos_?

Comment: @DoubleAA, depends how many questions are specifically about them. I haven't checked.

Comment: How would you tag this http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6556/759

Comment: @DoubleAA I guess as is (with [tag:blessing]). I don't know. My not being clear on the answer to that question, though, doesn't detract IMO from my answer here.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer not, unless a small number of cohesive categories are identified.  Right now I can search for all bracha-related questions with a single tag, and if I want only certain ones I can use additional search terms (the search default is now "and", not "or").  If we sub-divide the general tag, in order to find those questions I need to (1) know all the relevant tags and (2) search for them all individually.

If we do sub-divide, let's make sure the new tags have enough questions to warrant it.  Let's avoid onesies and twosies.  Currently the set identified in the question yields 8 questions; that feels small enough to me to do the multi-tag search.